# New Install - SharePoint Foundation 2013 - Missing Templates?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, site-template

Know this is a basic question, but I'm stumped.

Just installed SharePoint Foundation 2013 ... when I go to "Site Content", new subsite, I only see the following templates available:

1. Collaboration tab: Team Site and Blog
2. Enterprise: Basic Search Center

Shouldn't I see other default templates, such as "wiki" and "project sites"?

Answer (score 2):

That's all which comes with SharePoint Foundation, their is nothing missing.

If you need other templates, you have to go either standard or enterprise edition or use some coding.

Available Templates in SPF

- Collaboration - Team Site
- Collaboration - Blog
- Enterprise - Basic Search Center

Also read the below post for discontinued features in 2013.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742(v=office.15).aspx#section1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607742%28v=office.15%29.aspx#section1)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/discontinued-features-and-modified-functionality-in-microsoft-sharepoint-2013-HA102892827.aspx

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint Foundation 2013 comes only with those templates you already discovered.

To create a Wiki simply create a Team Site and add a Wiki Page Library app to it.

For project tracking like stuff there are apps like Issue Tracking and Tasks.

Anything beyond this needs customisation or third-party apps on Foundation.